# Python encoding Latin characters

Tags: python, encoding

I have a python file encoded as # -*- coding: latin-1 -*- and I just started using Pycharm with these files. The problem is that now when i run my script i get weird characters replacing characters such as ç and º

I already tried changing Pycharm's encoding to UTF-8, ISO 8859-1 , US-ASCII, System's Default encoding and the problem still continues. I'm running this on Linux.

Before using Pycharm, I was using Gedit to write my python script.

Comment: what characters are not getting printed properly?

Comment: HI, i already solved the problem. I had to change the encoding at the top of the file to utf-8 as well as the other scripts that my main script calls. thank you.