# Can I force character encoding inside a python script?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with characters not rendering properly.

**Background:** I am taking online courses to learn Python.  I use VSCode as my IDE along with various python extensions.

**Problem:** Some of the lessons I solve have characters that are beyond the 128 standard ASCII set.

**Sample:** [For clarity, this is the full script I'm dealing with.](https://gist.github.com/7ranceaddic7/c852fe81b4186679a60780c18fef23e2) The currently lesson has text containing a small e with acute (é) in a painting named Vétheuil in the Fog. Unfortunately that acute-e character is rendered as a placeholder (�) and ends up outputting: V�theuil in the Fog.

[image: image of character problem]

**Efforts:** I have done some searching and thought I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838427/python-encoding-latin-characters): including an encoding flag at the beginning of the python script like this:

`# coding=UTF-8`

No joy.

Am I tilting at a windmill / misunderstanding purpose or application?

**Money Question:** Is there a way to get the character to properly render when I run the script?

Comment: Are you running the script in VSCode Terminal? Do you have the issues on your OS integrated terminal?

Comment: An encoding comment declares what encoding your *script itself* is written in. It doesn't affect output handling. You're having a problem with how your terminal interprets output.

Comment: I do not know what OS you have, or if there are specific settings at that level, but I can confirm that when I run a simple script in PyCharm IDE and also in a command prompt on Windows, the text prints correctly with typical French accents. "la Commission européenne pour l’efficacité de la justice révèle que la France consacre 69,50 euros par habitant à la justice". This was rendered by simple text = r'la Commission européenne ...' and print(text) in python 3.6

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, that's what I was missing,, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Unicode characters to be displayed correctly, you'll need to use a terminal, that supports Unicode or change the terminal settings to work with Unicode, in case the terminal provides that option.

Of course the same way you can make the terminal able to display only extended ascii characters like "é" (as long as you have a terminal that provides this functionality), in case you don't need more characters.

Comment: Yep the terminal is displaying correctly.  It seems I have confused the 'OUTPUT' panel with the 'TERMINAL panel.  The OUTPUT is not displaying correctly while the TERMINAL is.

Answer (score 0):

This has been sufficiently addressed.

VSCode Panel displays different things via tabs below the editor region.  The OUTPUT tab has the displayed different and therefore becomes a question of my setup; not error as the TERMINAL tab displays characters as expected.  So, there is no problem to be solved beyond my misunderstand of what was happening.

As @user2357112supportsMonica also provided "An encoding comment declares what encoding your script itself is written in," not how the output is rendered.

Thank you all for helping me through this.

Just to cap this topic.  A PERFECT solution to this is provided here:

https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/general-nerdiness-questions/541682/7?u=coreblaster01537